# JSON format in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the JSON format like below in Swift code. Please help

Currently having working code below,

```
let jsonDict = ["UserID": user_id, "UserName": user_name, "User No": user_AccNo, "UserAddress": user_AccAddress, "User Type": user_AccType] as [String : Any]
        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: [])

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/vnd.kafka.v2+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.httpBody = jsonData
```

I want to change this code to input the following format JSON data:

```
'{"records":[{"value":{"UserID":"user_id"}}]}'
```

To apply for below POST request programmatically,

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
      --data '{"records":[{"value":{"foo":"bar"}}]}' "http://localhost:8082/topics/jsontest"
```

Please advise me how to format the JSON to fit this format in Swift:

```
{"records":[{"value":{"UserID":"user_id"}}]}
```

Comment: The desired output JSON is a dictionary whose `"records"` key has a value that is an _array_ consisting of one dictionary. Your code does not make the array or the surrounding dictionary.

Comment: You misunderstood the format of your JSON. We don't need the code of request. What you need to do is understand what kind of object (Dict, Array, String, etc.) you want, and to check the value do `let jsonStr = String(data:jsonData, encoding:.utf8)`. You can use an online "Beautifier" of your target JSON, it may help you identify what's dict and what's array, and each sublevel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for arrays and dictionaries is quite similar in Swift

- A dictionary is `[key: value, key: value]`
- An array is `[value, value, value]`

---

So lets create your dictionary from inside outwards, the inner dictionary is

```
["UserID" : user_id]
```

which is the value for key `value`

```
["value" : ["UserID" : user_id]]
```

which is wrapped in an array

```
[["value" : ["UserID" : user_id]]]
```

which is the value for key `records`

```
["records" : [["value" : ["UserID" : user_id]]]]
```

As the dictionary is heterogenous, it must be annotated

```
let jsonDict : [String:Any] = ["records" : [["value" : ["UserID" : user_id]]]]
```

Comment: let jsonDict [String:Any] = {"records" : [{"value" : {UserID": user_id, "UserName": user_name, "UserNo": user_AccNo, "UserAddress": user_AccAddress, "User Type": user_AccType}}]}